# Disabling customer login & registration on checkout in Magento

Tags: email, magento, authentication, registration, checkout

I've been looking for a few days now for a way to disable the automatic customer registration that occurs when a customer finishes an order in the checkout in Magento. What happens is that the user is logged in to his or her account, and two emails are sent. One containing the order confirmation, and another one, welcoming the user as a customer, including his or her account information.

What I'd like to do is to disable the email containing the welcome, and disable the registration/ login of the account.

Like I said, I've been trying to find some leads on where to look for a few days now, but to no avail. I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure out what files to look at, and also what parts of those files.

Also, maybe I should mention that the website is using a One Step Checkout.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your system setting you need to make changes in one of the two files listed below. Copy the templates to your custom theme folder and make the changes as needed to remove the login section and links.

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The login-section and links are already disabled. Though, Magento still automatically registers customers, generates a password, sends an email with the users login information and logs in the user after a purchase taking them to a success-page with a link to their dashboard. That's what I want to disable.

Comment: It seem to me that you have a custom module that is converting guest customer to register customer on checkout. By default (magento v1.7) to my knowledge should not send a welcome email when a customer check out as guest. It only send a email when a admin create an admin create a order. Take a look at all your custom modules

Comment: Thank you. It seems I've found the file. Though, it contains 2632 rows. Any idea what I should be looking for? Changing all the "METHOD_REGISTER" to "METHOD_GUEST" wouldn't do much more than corrupt the script I suppose, haha.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way to do this (without me know your reason for converting guest to registered customer). Is to comment out the line that send email... You should be looking for a line  `$quote->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $quote->getStoreId());` by default it is in `createOrder()` of `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`

Comment: Of course, :) I've just not had time to test it just yet. I will on Friday hopefully,  :)